# Return value int&

Tags: c++

I have a code like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int c=0;
int& abc()
{
    c++;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    cout << c << endl;
    int f = abc();
    cout << c << " " << f << endl;
    f++;
    cout << c << " " << f << endl;
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
0
1 1
1 2
```

Now the function abc returns an integer reference. So the statement `int f=abc();` should point integers f and c to the same address. But why the statement f++ is not affecting the value of c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because while `abc()` returns an int by reference, `f` doesn't "grab" this reference, but rather grabs the value the returned reference points to. If you want `f` to grab the reference, you need to define it as a reference type.

Do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int c=0;
int& abc()
{
    c++;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    cout << c << endl;
    int &f = abc();
    cout << c << " " << f << endl;
    f++;
    cout << c << " " << f << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int &f = abc();
```

Because your `f` is not a reference.It just a variable that be assigned a value of `c`.You should write it look like above.

Answer (score 0):

```
int f = abc();
^^^ // This type is 'int' not 'int&'
```

You're type for `f` is `int` which is no the same as `int&` and results in creating a copy. Therefore, instead of `f` being a reference to `c` it is a separate and distinct value that is initialized to the same value as stored in `c` when it is returned from `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `abc()` returns a reference. But `f` is just an integer variable. Therefore what`int f=abc()` does is assigning the value of `c` to `f`.
When you call f++ it only change the `f` variables value. It does not change the value of `c`. because `f` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In following code: `int f = abc()` **f** is a copy of the value of **c**, these two values are distinct. When you perform **++f** you are incrementing the copy **f** which will have no effect on **c**. When you do the following: `int &f = abc()` you are creating a reference variable **f** which is bound to the value of **c** and hence as **f** is an alias for the variable **c**, any changes made to **f** are made to **c**.